# Any good tools that easily help me write/mantain WSDL files?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Hi there being new to the 'write-contract-first' webservice area i was wondering if there are any good and preferably opensource tools that could help me in writing my wsdl files.

I know that i can write the WSDL with a text/XML editor but this is a cumbersome and error- prone approach.

I am using Apache CXF for my implementation, any hints and tips are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse project WTP (Web Tools Platform) includes a graphical WSDL editor. It has a similiar editor for XML schemas (XSD) too.

Either install one of the [prepackaged contributions](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) that include Web Tools already or add to an already installed installation of eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse has many tools to help you out with XML, WSDL and the likes. If you work a lot with XML then paying (small) license fees for software like Altova or Oxygen is money well spent.